# dgram in Nativescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, nativescript

Im trying to use the dgram library (https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/docs/api/dgram.html) with NativeScript.

I'm using

```
Node v4.4.7
tns version 2.1.1
npm version 2.15.8
Visual Studio version 1.3.0
```

Im trying to use the dgram like this:

```
var dgram = require('dgram');
var Buffer = require('buffer').Buffer;

var message = new Buffer('Knock');
var client = dgram.createSocket('udp4');
...
```

But when I start my app (`tns run android`) I get the following exception:

```
Failed to find module: "dgram" relative to: /app/tns_module
```

I tried to install the dgram as a plugin
tns plugin add dgram (doesn't exist...)

Any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**: You can't use it

Longer answer: You're trying to use a *Node* library. Node is a is a JavaScript runtime. NativeScript uses Google's V8 for Android and WebKit's JavaScriptCore on iOS. Node is just used as a development tool to help you set up and build your NativeScript project. Node is *not* running on your iPhone/iPad/Android.

Comment: Thanks. I hoped it was possible in some way, but I guess it is not.
Do you know any library that is usable for sending UDP packets?

Comment: Not that I know of, no, sorry. Try asking in the Slack channel ( https://nativescriptcommunity.slack.com/messages/general/ )